# Cпроектировать структуру данных, позволяющую выполнять операции над набором областей

Tags: mysql, структуры-данных

*Прошу помощи с задачей из учебника.*

**Задача.** На двумерной плоскости размером NxM точек

```
(1<=N<2^20, 1<=M<2^14)
```

имеется набор прямоугольных областей. Каждая область характеризуется координатами верхней левой `(x1, y1)` и правой нижней точек `(x2, y2). (x2>=x1, y2>=y1).`

Требуется спроектировать структуру данных, позволяющую выполнять следующие операции над набором областей: 
Добавление области; 
Добавление набора областей; 
Удаление области; 
Удаление набора областей; 
Удаление всех областей содержащихся в заданной; 
Поиск всех областей, пересекающих/содержащихся в заданной области

**Дополнительная задача, сложная:** Структура должна позволять выполнять сдвиг заданной произвольной области вниз\вверх или вправо\влево.

**Критерии оценки:**

Производительность; 
Объем потребляемой памяти.

Comment: Какие идеи рассматривались? Что не получилось?

Comment: Прочитал 415 из 560 страниц Бэйли изучаем MySQL - решения пока и близко не видно. Если лениво\некогда писать решние - подскажите хоть что гуглить (фразы из задачи тоже не находятся).

Comment: От Вас хотят получить r-tree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В БД вам достаточно хранить 4 координаты (x1, y1, x2, y2)  + идентификатор области (если нужен). Все остальное можно делать с помощью запросов и математики. 
Например, чтобы узнать входит ли область1 в область2, должно выполняться условие, что верхняя левая граница обасти2 должна буть выше и левее чем у области1, соответственно нижняя правая ниже и правее. 
Запрос который выберет все области которые входят в заданную выглядит так:

```
SELECT x1, y1, x2, y2 
FROM sets 
WHERE x1 < :x1 AND y1 < :y1 AND x2 > :x2 AND y2 > :y2
```

где `:x1, :y1, :x2, :y2`  - координаты области в которой осуществляется поиск.